# Почему ласты клеют?

Tags: фразеология

По поводу смерти существует множество эпитетов (подозреваю, их придумали, чтобы напрямую не называть вещи своими именами и не накликать). Один из них - "склеить ласты". Оборот, конечно, шутливый или же пренебрежительный и совершенно непонятный.
Какие ласты? И почему их надо клеить (или не надо?)? ))

Comment: Извините, клеЯт, а не клеЮт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение «склеил ласты» берет свое начало, как и многие жаргонизмы,  из тюремного жаргона. Дело в том, что ластами в тюрьме называли руки. А когда кто-нибудь из заключенных умирал, ему складывали на груди руки одна на другую, от трупного окоченения руки склеивались. Вот почему про умершего говорили: «ласты склеил». Это идиома,т.к. в литерат. языке отдельные его части не образуют исходной семантики.

Руки умершему и по сей день складывают таким же образом в обычных больницах и моргах, а потому выражение прижилось и в специфичном медицинском сленге. Впоследствии эта идиома прочно вошла в обиход русского человека наравне с другими жаргонными обозначениями смерти, такими как «отбросил копыта», «сыграл в ящик» или «дал дуба».

К слову, скрещенные в области запястья руки, сложенные на груди покойного, знак весьма символичный, он обозначает смирение усопшего перед лицом вечности или Бога. Примечательно, что даже в годы советского атеизма умерших хоронили только в такой позе.

Некоторые считают, что выражение «склеил ласты» имеет параллель с миром животных. А точнее - с миром земноводных. Имеется в виду ассоциация холодного тела умершего человека с мертвой лягушкой, возможно, мокрые и холодные земноводные и напоминали людям окоченелые трупы. У кого-то ассоциации с пингвином(только почему склеил?)

В этом случае данное сочетание слов приобретает скорее ироническую, негативную окраску.  ведь про умерших родных и близких так говорить не принято( говорят: «отдал душу», «испустил дух», «отошел в мир иной», «предстал перед Богом или Аллахом»).
Впрочем, подобную «бытовую» версию рождения идиомы лингвисты не поддерживают.

http://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-893062-kak-poyavilos-vyrazhenie-lasty-skleil

Answer (score 2):

> *…ластами в тюрьме называли руки.*

Скорее, **ноги**.

> **ЛАСТЫ**, ласт, мн. Ноги, ботинки (обычно большого размера). ♦ **ласты
>   склеить** — умереть.
>
> [Словарь русского арго. 
>   http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_6412
>   ]

И в других фразеологизмах под  ластами скорее понимаются **ноги.** См.:

[image]

Comment: да и вообще ласты это атрофированные ноги, у всех тюленей и им подобным.

Comment: Не атрофированные, а скорее, видоизмененные

Comment: slava1947,не путайте молодёжный жаргон с тюремным. Рада за Вас, что не привелось его знать, к несчастью, иногда приходится общаться и слышать, как братья здороваются: "Давай ласты!". Там же можно услышать "Ласты скрутили"- арестовали. А в молодёжном сленге ассоциации на рыбацкую тему и тему пловцов, только "ласты склеил"не из той оперы.

Comment: http://samlib.ru/m/mazurin/slowarx.shtml